# Не удается записать в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, listview

Есть класс, содержащий строку String и целое число int
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше объявляю массив с этим классом, инициализирую.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполнение *listview* через обработчик событий *Click* по нажатию на *bttn_Calculate*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**НО ПОЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ ПРИ ПЕРВОЙ ИТЕРАЦИИ ЦИКЛА. ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здесь не любят код в картинках. И добавьте, пожалуйста, еще тег WinForms или WPF, т.к. ListView есть там и там.

Comment: `Items` пустой же. Был опыт `php`? Ничто само собой в коллекцию не добавляется.

Comment: Два столбца же создано.

Answer (score 2):

Какой-то странный у вас стиль, как будто вы только что из C++ в C# переехали.

ваши свойства можно было бы написать так

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

ну или так (финансовые переменные надо хранить в `decimal`)

```
private double _Price;
public double Price
{
    get { return _Price; }
    set { _Price = value; }
}
```

Вместо массива лучше использовать `List<TourCategory> TourCategories`, еще лучше `ObservableCollection<TourCategory> TourCategories`, т.к. этот тип коллекции позволяет автоматически обновлять UI вслед за изменением состава коллекции.

После создания коллекции можно просто сделать так

```
this.listView.ItemsSource = TourCategories;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавляете в SubItems, а нужно в listView.Items. Удалите .SubItems из кода.

Answer (score 1):

Что происходит в цикле: вы обращаетесь к коллекции Items по индексу (Items[i]). Но Items пустой, в нем не элементов. Вам надо добавить элемент в коллекцию, прежде чем к нему можно обращаться. Делается это методом `Items.Add(...)`.